# Renew CSRF_TOKEN

Tags: django

I have an application and I want the user to be able to change the password, while staying logged in.

I'm doing this:

```
request.user.set_password(password)
request.user.save()
request.user.backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
auth_login(request, request.user)
```

It changes the password and I log in again to keep the user session. But apparently if I do this the CSRF_TOKEN which I have saved in my js client as a variable is no longer valid and I can't use it for POST requests.

Is there a way to renew the CSRF_TOKEN and send it to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the view, you can get the token with this:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
print unicode(csrf(request)['csrf_token'])
```

As far as how to update your js client I would need more details about it before giving good advice. I imagine it would be as simple as returning the new token from the login request. I imagine your login is ajax so you could return the new token in the response and write some JS to update your stored token:

```
import json
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"csrf_token": unicode(csrf(request)['csrf_token'])), content_type="application/json")
```